# Associate method

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to associate related records of an entity to a newly created one. The pluggin triggers on creation and pre-operation.

The error occurs when trying to associate the collection to the new entity : "new_ligneContrat With Id = ad630ba6-684e-e111-92e3-00155d151905 Does Not Exist"

Here is my code :

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Instanciation des services

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(null);


            Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            EntityReference contrats = (EntityReference)target.Attributes["new_contratsid"];

            FetchExpression fetch = new FetchExpression(@"
                    <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical'>
                      <entity name='" + context.PrimaryEntityName + "'><link-entity name='new_contrats' alias='nombreligne' from='new_contratsid' to='new_contratsid'><filter type='and'><condition attribute='new_contratsid' value='" + contrats.Id + "' operator='eq'></condition></filter></link-entity></entity></fetch>");

            EntityCollection lines = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetch);

                  // Vérification qu'il y a au moins une ligne de contrat associée
            if (lines.Entities.Any())
            {

                var first = lines.Entities.Last();

                if (first.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 1)
                {
                    FetchExpression query = new FetchExpression(@"
                        <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical'>
                        <entity name='incident'><filter type='and'><condition attribute='new_lignecontrat' value='"+first.Id+"' operator='eq'/></filter></entity></fetch>");

                    EntityCollection incident = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

                    if (incident.Entities.Any())
                    {


                        foreach (var e in incident.Entities)
                        {
                           e.Attributes["new_lignecontrat"] = new EntityReference (target.LogicalName, target.Id);
                        }


                 }
              }
           }
```

What is wrong???

Thanks in advance!!

Edit 1: ok seems logical since the record does not exist yet ><. Just one thing : How can I change the value of a lookup field? What is its type?

Edit 2: I've got no error when executing my code, but fields of the incident entity do not update ><'....I've tested my code with invalidPluginExceptions and the end of the code is reached...Here is the code :

Edit 3 : Code updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your original question and its edit, yeah, you can't associate the record with another record when the core database operation hasn't been done yet.

> [Pre-operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx#bkmk_PipelineStages): Stage in the pipeline for plug-ins that are to execute before the main
>   system operation. Plug-ins registered in this stage are executed
>   within the database transaction.

So to handle association, you can either change the stage to post-operation, or have one `IPlugin` class handle the pre-operation stage and another handle the post-operation stage, either in one or multiple projects.

To answer the edit, lookup fields are of the class [`EntityReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.aspx). (Looks like you're working with a 1:N relationship?)

To answer the second edit, I don't see anywhere in your code snippet where you assign the new `EntityReference` to your target `Entity`. Moreover, you don't have to issue an `Update` request to the service in the pre-operation stage because the core database operation has not been performed yet. You can just set the attribute of the `Entity` to be equal to the the value of your choice, and this change will be carried over to the database.

```cs
if (entity.Attributes.ContainsKey("new_lignecontrat"))
{
    entity.Attributes["new_lignecontrat"] = YourEntityReference;
}
else //attribute not included in the plugin operation
{
    entity.Attributes.Add("new_lignecontrat", YourEntityReference);
}
```

Microsoft has a demonstration of this concept in the SDK:

> \sdk\samplecode\cs\plug-ins\accountnumberplugin.cs

Comment: Thank you for tour answer Peter! Triggering the plugins on post-opération is ont problem. I'm indeed working on a 1:N relationship. What I need actually Is that when a new "new_lignecontrat" is created, the lookup field related to the previous one in the incident entity is to be updated.                  So would à simple e.Attributes.getValue<EntityReference>("new_lignecontrat")= new EntityReference (target.logicalName,target.Id); do the job?

Comment: @MademoiselleLenore: That's right. You *have* to use the `Associate` method for N:N relationships, but for 1:N relationships, you have the luxury of also being able to assign the `EntityReference` to the entity directly, so that will work fine.

Comment: Thanks again Peter, still no result. I've edited the whole code.

Comment: @MademoiselleLenore: I think looking over your code there and finding the problem might be out of the scope of this question (though I have some thoughts - is `e.Attributes["new_lignecontrat"]` instantiated, for instance?). I can only add two suggestions: try [debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx), and try using [early-bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx) instead of late-bound classes, which takes care of any attribute instantiation for you.

Comment: @MademoiselleLenore: Some delay! But glad it's working now. :)